# Does Ubuntu 14.04 recognize the SSD drivers automatically?

Tags: installation

Is it necessary to reset the memory configuration on a computer with both memories?
If so, how can I do it?

Comment: SSD is not "memory"... please clarify your question? Thanks!

Comment: @h.j.k. Wikipedia "A solid-state drive (SSD) (also known as a solid-state disk[1][2][3] or electronic disk,[4] though it contains no actual "disk" of any kind or motors to "drive" the disks) is a data storage device using integrated circuit assemblies as memory to store data persistently. SSD technology uses electronic interfaces compatible with traditional block input/output (I/O) hard disk drives, thus permitting simple replacement in common applications.[5] Also, new I/O interfaces like SATA Express are created to keep up with speed advancements in SSD technology."

Comment: And what is this "reset the memory configuration" for a Solid State Drive you are talking about? Do you mean formatting an SSD?

Comment: @ I wonder if I need to set it up for it to work or if Linux automatically recognizes it.

Comment: I'll strongly suggest you edit your question then... so you're asking if during a Linux installation (distro, if you know), can it also install the right SSD drivers? I don't perform any Linux installation myself, this is as much as I can help you out with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience with installing Linux distributions, SSDs have been recognized and used just like normal hard drives with no problems that I can detect. This is a more exhaustive article about tuning and using SSDs with Linux: https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/SSD_Tuning_for_Linux